# Different behavior when trying to swap two variables using {} and std::make_pair()

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, std-pair, stdtuple

I was trying to swap two variables using `std::tie()` as per the following code (I am aware of `std::swap`, I was just trying this out of curiosity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using std::cin; using std::tie; 
using std::cout; using std::endl;
using std::make_pair;

int main() {
    int a = 2, b = 10;
    cout << "Before Swapping using {}" << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b < <endl;
    tie(a, b) = {b, a};
    cout << "After Swapping using {}" << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;

    a = 2, b = 10;
    cout << "Before Swapping using make_pair()" << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;
    tie(a, b) = make_pair(b, a);
    cout << "After Swapping using make_pair()" << endl;
    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test`.

But the output was this:

```
Before Swapping using {}
a: 2 b: 10
After Swapping using {}
a: 10 b: 10
Before Swapping using make_pair()
a: 2 b: 10
After Swapping using make_pair()
a: 10 b: 2
```

So, my question is, since we can write `{a, b}` instead of writing `std::make_pair(a, b)` everytime (C++11 onwards), why are these two versions giving different output?

My guess was that the following line

```
std::tie(a, b) = {b, a};
```

is not making a pair and for some reason only mutating the value of `a`. But I am not sure.

Comment: looks like undefined behavior... `a` is being set to the value of `b` and then the updated `a` is written to `b`... A sequence point problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 gives the answer below.  You are right that you can construct a pair with {} but the compiler needs to know that that is what you are constructing, at that point.

Answer (score 13):

`tie(a, b) = {b, a};`

will use `std::tuple<int&, int&> operator = (std::tuple<int&, int&>&&)`.
and not `std::tuple<int&, int&> operator = (std::tuple<int, int>&&)` as you expect.

`std::tie(a, b)` is a `std::tuple<int&, int&>`.
`std::tuple` has several `operator =`, but the only viable with (non typed) `{a, b}` are the copy/move assignment.

Answer (score 5):

`{b, a}` makes a `std::tuple<int&, int&>` while `std::make_pair` makes a `std::pair<int, int>`.

Consider what happens with `std::pair<int&, int&>`. It's essentially assigning one of the variables to the other, and then trying to assign the other to the first. It's equivalent to doing `a = b; b = a;` or `b = a; a = b;`.

Comment: It doesn't make a `pair<int&, int&>`, it makes a `tuple<int&, int&>`.

Answer (score 3):

just use make_tuple

```
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a);
```

it's the same thing a=b or b=a;